# QT: How do I share same object in all .ui

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to QT and this is probably (I hope) easy to solve, but i really dont know how to do it.

My program is quite easy, mainwindow with few buttons, but what my problem is:

In main.cpp I load a list from file and save it in a pointer (ex: listPointer) and I need to acces the info, from that list from many different .ui and .cpp (I mean, the Qt Class Form Pack, .ui .h .cpp).

I don´t know which way is the best to do this. In mainwindow.h I added a list pointer to get the reference and in the .cpp acces it via this->listPointer and that works, but when i try to acces it from other Qt class (ex: Search.cpp) my app just crashes, obviusly becouse I'm trying to access wrong memory block.

So my problem is, how do I share this list to all the QT Objects.

I hope you understand my problem, english is not my native so maybe u dont.

Answer (score 0):

If your main window exists throughout the life of your application and you only need a one instance of your main window, you can simply make your main window class singleton. You can keep your list pointer as a member of main window and add a getter method to it.

Then you can access your list from anywhere of your application like this

```
QList<String>* list = MyMainWindow::getInstance()->getList();
```

Comment: But I tried like this and didnt work:

In MainWindow.h:

public:

List<myClass*>* lista;


In Search.cpp (example):

void Search::ShowMyClass()
{
MainWindow w;

w.lista->cursorFoward;
}

Maybe its not the same but i dont see the difference

Comment: Also I'm using my own list implementation, so i can't use <list>, forgot to say that

Comment: What did the debugger say? Where exactly the program crashes and what is the cause reported by debugger?

Comment: Just says, it crashed, unexpected crash, no details

Comment: Also, the other windows are not set as childs of mainwindow

Comment: Did you check whether `w.lista` is null before calling `cursorForward()`?